# Userscript to Highlight Text works in Console but not Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, highlight, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the following code to load upon (or I guess, after) page load and automatically highlight certain words or phrases on the page. Right now, the code does not initiate unless I plug it into the console. The code I've been testing is highly influenced by a past thread ([Greasemonkey: Highlight many words in a HTML-File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535881/greasemonkey-highlight-many-words-in-a-html-file)) and is listed below:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Highlight Text
// @description Highlights text within HTML
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==

function highlightWord(word) {
    var xpath = "//text()[contains(., '" + word + "')]";
    var texts = document.evaluate(xpath, document.body, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for (n = 0; n < texts.snapshotLength; n++) {
        var textNode = texts.snapshotItem(n);
        var p = textNode.parentNode;
        var a = [];
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        textNode.nodeValue.split(word).forEach(function(text, i) {
            var node;
            if (i) {
                node = document.createElement('span');
                node.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
                node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(word));
                frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            if (text.length) {
                frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
            }
            return a;
        });
        p.replaceChild(frag, textNode);
    }
}
highlightWord('sample');
```

For example, I would like to highlight the word "sample" from the following page: https://www.snapsurveys.com/survey-software/sample-surveys/

I haven't been able to get the code to highlight text automatically on page load. I've done a little research and I think the page may be AJAX-influenced, thus the grants at the top. Right now, upon page load nothing happens, yet when I manually insert the code into the console of the page, it works fine and the specified text indeed gets highlighted. It seems like a really simple fix, but I'm clearly glossing over something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have tampermonkey running to test with, but maybe try binding to the window `load` event instead of calling the function immediately (`window.addEventListener("load", () => highlightWord('sample'));`)? Or possibly just setting a timeout will do it (`window.setTimeout(() => highlightWord('sample'), 1000);`)

Comment: I think you should include the site address in `@include` or `@match` tag in the script. Else it will not run.

Comment: Why don't you use the template that Tampermonkey offers when creating a new script?

Comment: So after taking your suggestions I figured out the problem. I failed to realize that highlightword is case sensitive and I also used the @include for the specific sites I wanted. Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score -1):

I failed to realize that highlightword is case sensitive and I also used the @include for the specific sites i wanted, and now it works fine.

Comment: You should make this a comment, or edit your own question post.